# Cauchy-Riemann and Analytic Functions

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Using the Cauchy-Riemann conditions, tell if $f(z) = z^{*}$ is analytic

I have tried this:

$Z = x + iy$

$f(x + iy) = Z^{*} = x - iy$

$U(x,y) = x$

$V(x,y) = -y$

$U_x = 1$ Deriving respect to $x$

$V_x = 0$ Deriving respect to $x$

$U_y = 0$ Deriving respect to $y$

$V_y = -1$ Deriving respect to $y$

Then $U_x <> V_y$ and I suppose that $f(z) = z^{*}$ is not analytic.
But I'm not sure, I think I'm wrong. Could you help me, please?

Comment: Check your answer for $V_y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that $V_y = -1$.  Since $U_x \not = V_y$, the Cauchy Riemann equations are not satisfied.

Comment: I think, that this is not the point, I need to demonstrate f(z) = z* is analytic. So, if  Cauchy Riemann equations are not satisfied, could I say that f(z) is not analytic?

Comment: @LuisArmando If a function is analytic, then it must satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations.  Since the Cauchy Riemann equations are not satisfied, it can't be analytic.